# Joining Cartesian plane and Complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, intuition

[image]Is it correct to join the Cartesian Plane with the Complex Plane, the Cartesian plane being composed of the `x` and `y` axes (real numbers), and the complex plane being the `z` axis (imaginary numbers)?
I ask this because every real number has its imaginary part.

This representation, in which the z axis is the complex numbers, is this representation correct?

What I want to know is if conceptually I can represent a number as in the graph, since every number has a real and an imaginary part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What was the motivation for the complex plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715107/what-was-the-motivation-for-the-complex-plane)

Comment: Actually, I would like to know if I can create a 3-axis plane, `z` being imaginary numbers?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. But still, your question is rather vague. What do you mean by "join"? There certainly is a natural bijection $\mathbb C \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by $(x+iy,z) \mapsto (x,y,z)$. Is that all you are asking, or do you want there to be more structure (e.g. vector space structure; field structure; ...)?

Comment: I made a graphic representation to facilitate understanding

Comment: Not sure this is the question, but when people speak of "a complex number $z$" it does not refer to the Cartesian $z$-axis, which represents only a real number, not a complex number.

Comment: The diagram and edits don't help, for me at least. In this setting, $x + iz$ and $y + iz$ are complex, but is that the question?

Comment: It's just that I always see the Cartesian Plane and Complex Plane shown separately, but in my understanding, they can be presented together. I just want to know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: They can be presented together. But your presentation is incorrect. The "together presentation" is that the complex number $z = x+iy \in \mathbb C$ is identified with the ordered pair $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$. If you had drawn a picture with no $z$-axis, and with one glowing red point on the $x$--$y$ plane labelled something like this $$z=x+iy \leftrightarrow (x,y)$$ then that would have been perfect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation